# Validation rule for country code

Tags: validation-rule, validation

I have custom metadata which is **'All Country Code'**

And I have custom field there which is **'Codes'**

Is it possible to add validation rule for specific country in the following way:
if '44' (United Kingdom) chosen, add 0 to after country code (440).

Or any other option. I need it because some countries has optional zero in their numbers, so I need to make sure if someone pass/remove 0 from the phone number nothing will change. They still will receive sms.

Looking for for any ideas on how to manage it.

Comment: Hello, you might use Libphonenumber and save all phones in one format.

Comment: Formula field: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields